Stuck in login loop using Spring Security
I am using Spring Security for my RESTful application. Here is SecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
            throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v3/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}

When I try to register new user with JWT-authenticated POST on the link http://localhost:8080/api/v3/auth/register I get such error: Error: Exceed maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:8080/login.
How can I get a login form to register a new user or authorize an existing one? Here is my authentication controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v3/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticate(request));
    }
}


Does the following post answer your question? spring-boot Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop

Please do not use JWTs as sessions, there is a reason that type of filter does not exist in spring security. If you are a beginner dont just follow poorly written blogs that make up home made security. Read the official docs and use the built in features. Jwts should never be returned to browsers
